# Usage of startscript.xml in weblogic to generate sh files during domain creation process

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, weblogic12c, weblogic9.x

I used weblogic for my learning purpose and i have read in weblogic documentation that using startscript.xml one can update modify sh and cmd files and place in domains root directory during the domain creation process.

For example using below snipped in startscript.xml i can update domainEnv.sh to set required GC arguments

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<scripts>
<script type="ext" version="3" path="bin" name="setDomainEnv">
<blockinsert name="section_marker_30">  
  <setenv name="JAVA_OPTIONS" scope="global">
    <value preserve="true">%JAVA_OPTIONS%
     '-Xloggc:${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers/${SERVER_NAME}/logs/gc_${SERVER_NAME}.lg -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails
     -XX:+DisableExplicitGC')
    </value>
   </setenv>
  </blockinsert>
 </script>
</scripts>
```

The above snippet works and i can see the JAVA_OPTIONS getting updated in setDomainenv.sh but what i did not understand is the significance of name=section_marker_30.I tried browsing oracle documentations but there seems to be no documentation reg the same.Can any one help me in understanding this and put me in right direction?

Thanks
VishwanathB

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the `name="section_marker_30"` syntax, it appears to be a 1-up counter for each section of the `startscript.xml` file.

I agree with you, the documentation is very poor.